# I want to hide my views in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, view

We are a small BI consultancy firm. The BI application gets data from the server using a view.

As we are growing we need to make out queries/views safe so they cant be copied or reused without our permission. They will be running on clients server machines.

I would like to know if there is any way of hiding/protecting the views so that only I can access it in case of changes needed otherwise no one can see the code.

Regards

Comment: No, there is not. Your client's DBA will always be able to see the views (including their definition). There's just no way to prevent that.

Comment: Unless you are DBA of the client DB and the client has no DBA acceess to  its DB, you can not.

Comment: If you really want to protect this you should use a web service instead and host the sql server on your end. But to be honest, there really isn't likely any ground breaking logic in your queries. The other option is to have a decent SLA with your client so they agree not to copy them. That at least gives you some recourse if they do.

Comment: Thinking paranoid: even if they don't yet have DBA access, if it's hosted on their physical machine then they *can* get it.

Answer (score 2):

If you can count on them not having the sa password or `sysadmin` role membership, then you can use the `VIEW DEFINITION` permission to control who can see your view's definition:

```
DENY VIEW DEFINITION ON someview TO username
```

You cannot, of course, forbid them from seeing the *names* of your views -- the application itself needs to be able to select from the view.

If they will have `sysadmin` permission, then you can use `WITH ENCRYPTION` on your view definitions to prevent *anyone*, even sa, from retrieving the definition.

```
CREATE VIEW someview WITH ENCRYPTION AS ....
```

Since you yourself won't be able to retrieve it from the database, you'd better keep the view definition in a separate source control system. (Which you should do anyway.)

EDIT: As marc_s rightly points out, `WITH ENCRYPTION` isn't really safe. There are ways to decrypt it anyway if you're determined. See [this answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/60142/23463).

[Source](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1828/options-for-hiding-sql-server-code/)

Comment: Interesting. How does one go about modifying something like that?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking, @Forklift. Modifying a view that has been created `with encryption`? You need the source, saved somewhere else, and you paste it into `ALTER VIEW someview WITH ENCRYPTION AS ...`

Comment: But any DBA worth his salt will have the link to the scripts to **decrypt** any `WITH ENCRYPTION` views very easily - that's just not anything very useful in the end... (it *pretends* to be a safeguard - but it's really not ...)

Comment: @RossPresser, thanks for the information. I hadn't heard of `WITH ENCRYPTION` before. Sounds like Right Click -> Modify wouldn't work at all in this case.

Comment: @marc_s I suppose you're right. :( I should have known it was too good to be true.

Comment: @marc_s if that's the case, what do they expect is the value of being able to `ENCRYPT` at all?

Comment: Edited answer to admit defeat (including a link to another question about it). It's just an obstacle, not a wall, @Forklift.

Comment: @RossPresser, no worries; I am not OP, just seeking more information on a concept I was unfamiliar with.

Comment: It's impossible even in theory. The SQL engine itself needs the definition to be able to do the select. And sa has potentially as much power as the engine; even if you invented a way to use PKI to encrypt it, the engine has to get it decrypted, so the key must be accessible to engine; so sa has to be able to get the key too.